# ¿Como puedo compartir una pantalla?

Tags: linux

Holan uso Ubuntu Bionic (18.04) y tengo 2 pantallas, si yo quiero compartir pantalla, solo me permite compartir los 2 monitores al mismo tiempo no unicamente un monitor.

Les voy a adjuntar una imagen con un ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es solo un ejemplo, he usado otros servicios y nunca permite a linux compartir solo una pantall

Comment: Quizá no te valga la respuesta, pero yo lo que hago es desactivar el monitor secundario y así comparto una pantalla. Lo hago porque si comparto las 2 el otro lo verá muy pequeño, y no consigo compartir solo una, como tú. En cualquier caso, veo poco probable que encuentres una respuesta aquí, pero bueno, ojalá me equivoque.

Answer (score 2):

Éste es un ***conocido problema*** que afecta a distribuciones de linux, hay un [**reporte**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=437507) abierto desde el 2014 y aún hoy no se ha resuelto el problema.

### Solución Temporal:

El [comentario 18](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=437507#c18) dentro del mismo hilo de discusión sugiere una solución alternativa, donde básicamente utilizas [**VLC**](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) para ***capturar la pantalla*** y luego pasas ***la ventana de VLC*** mediante un servicio que te permita compartirla.

Esta solución presenta un buen par de inconvenientes y está lejos de ser adecuada pero podrías intentarla.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por el comentario... yo usaba [AnyDesk](https://anydesk.com/es) para esto... nunca pensé que con VLC se pueda hacer... bueno leí otra pregunta donde se podía creando algo así una especie de monitor virtual pero como estaba en ingles no entendí ni siquiera sé se en un solución real pues no entendí

Comment: Podrias compartir el enlace hacia la pregunta que mencionas?, quisiera hecharle un vistazo a ver si puedo ayudarte a buscar una mejor solución, tambien tengo curiosidad por este "monitor virtual".

Comment: Este es el link de la pregunta... Como esta en inglés no entiendo... [link pregunta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156412)